# Haskell modulo similar to JavaScript (takes sign into account and works for non-integers)

Tags: haskell, modulo

In JavaScript:

```js
console.log(13 % 5);
// Expected output: 3

console.log(-13 % 5);
// Expected output: -3
```

I need the same in Haskell. I did

```hs
:{
modulo :: Double -> Int -> Double
modulo a p = 
    let p' = fromIntegral p
    in
    if a > 0 
        then a - fromIntegral(p * floor(a/p'))  
        else a - fromIntegral(p * ceiling(a/p'))
:}
```

That seems to work (at least I find the same results as the JavaScript ones). Is there a better way?

Contrary to `rem`, it should work for a `Double` `a`:

```hs
ghci> modulo (-13.5) 5
-3.5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already exists, this is [**`rem :: Integral a => a -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:rem):

```
ghci> 13 `rem` 5
3
ghci> (-13) `rem` 5
-3
```

Haskell has two "pairs" of functions regarding division and modulo: `div` and `mod`, which truncate towards negative infinity; and `quot` and `rem` which truncate towards zero.

or for `RealFrac` types:

```
fracRem :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a
fracRem x y = x - fromIntegral (y * (truncate x `quot` y))
```

Comment: Nice but my modulo should be able to take a `Double` a.

Comment: Thanks. It should also work for a double b,  but exclusively the case  0.5, so it's not a problem I thnk. I check your code and I accept.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: the rest is likely due to the fact that floats can not represent any arbitrary floating point number

Comment: Willem> Yeah, in R both double numbers are accepted and this has some limitations.

Comment: The [`Data.Fixed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html) module offers `div'`, `mod'`, and `divMod'` for `Double`s (but no `quot'`/`rem'`). Personally, I find `quot` and `rem` bizarre and unlikely to have the desired behavior in most situations anyway -- their existence is mostly due to them being a tiny epsilon easier to implement in hardware. These days the difference is completely negligible on the scale of things processors do, but we're stuck with a historical decision made in a different era.

Comment: In fact I don't understand why there is `abs(modulo(a, 0.5)) * 2` in my code. Isn't it the same as `abs(modulo(2*a, 1))`?

Comment: No, it is rather `abs(modulo (2*a) 1) / 2`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: if you want to do modulo 1, so obtain the fractional part, you use `properFraction`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:properFraction